# Finite Cyclic group isomorphic to C

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $G$ is a cyclic group and $|G|=n$ ($n\in \Bbb Z_{\ge 1}$), then $G\cong C_n$.

Why does this statement not hold in both directions, i.e an if and only if statement?

Comment: The converse is in fact true, but that direction is more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

That statement (very obviously) holds in both directions. Sometimes, when the converse is glaringly obvious, the 'only if' is not written.